# Сложность алгоритма при чтении json обьекта

Tags: javascript, java, алгоритм

У меня есть следующий json файл:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если я буду читать его таким алгоритмом:

```
for (let index = 0; index < servers.length; index++) {
      const server = vm.servers[index];

      for (let i = 0; i < server.instances.length; i++) {
```

То сложность данного алгоритма будет - `O(n^2)` или `O(n)`?

Comment: В представленном коде вы ничего не читаете, сложность представленного алгоритма - произведение 2 переборов, но к чтению json это отношения не имееет.

Comment: Что вы под n имеете в виду?

Comment: O(m*n), где `n` - число серверов, а `m` - экземпляров :) Нет, если серьезно - то что такое у вас `n`? Если общее количество экземпляров, то, естественно, O(n) - вы же каждый считываете один раз.

Comment: И у вас каша в тегах